# Counting rows in SQL stament using grouping by incremnental variables

Tags: sql

Table I'm trying to get analytical result from  is voice calls record. Each call (one row) has duration in seconds (just int value, not datetime). I'm trying to get number of records grouped by 15 seconds spans like this:

```
+-------------------+
|Period | Count     |
+-------------------+
| 0-15  | 213421    |
|15-30  | 231123    |
|30-45  | 1234      |
+-------------------+
```

Starts of period is 0, end is 86400.

I've tried some combinations with setting variables for start and end and then incrementing them by 15, but i'm not very successful, and i can't understand what is going wrong.

Please help out. Thank you!

Comment: not enough clear info for an answer...

Answer (score 3):

The following query fits your needs:

```
SELECT
  (duration - duration % 15),
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  call
GROUP BY
  (duration - duration % 15)
ORDER BY
  1;
```

You can also add some string formatting, in case you need the output exactly as you described it:

```
SELECT
  (duration - duration % 15)::text || '-' || (duration - duration % 15 + 15)::text,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  call
GROUP BY
  (duration - duration % 15)
ORDER BY
  1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(span * 15, '-', span * 15 + 15), COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM    (
        SELECT  v.*, FLOOR(period / 15) AS span
        FROM    voice_calls v
        ) q
GROUP BY
        span
```

**UPDATE:**

The solution you posted will work, assuming there will always be more than 5760 rows.

But you better create a dummy rowset of `5760` rows and use it in `OUTER JOIN`:

```
CREATE TABLE spans (span INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT
INTO    spans
VALUES  (0),
        (1),
        ...
        (5759)

SELECT  span * 15, COUNT(*)
FROM    spans
LEFT JOIN
        calls
ON      call.duration >= span * 15
        AND call.duration < span * 15 + 15
GROUP BY
        span
```

It will be more efficient and sane, as it can neither underflow (if less than `5760` rows in `calls`), nor take to much time if there are millions of rows there.

Comment: Never thought about looking up FLOOR function, this query looks great but sadly it does not work.

#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias 

Apparently MySQL requires all derived tables to have aliases

Comment: One tiny problem with this query (IMHO) - when there are no records in a given group/span there is no row about that group/span in the result.

Comment: @Milen: Unfortunately, MySQL lacks generate_series. @op will need to create a table with 5760 records for the OUTER JOIN, I wasn't sure he wants it, but I'll add it if there's a requirement

Answer (score 0):

I think a query like this should work; You'll have to pivot the results yourself on the display though (eg, this query gets the results horizontally, you'll have to display them vertically):

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN CallLength BETWEEN 0 AND 15 THEN CallLength ELSE 0 END) AS ZeroToFifteen,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CallLength BETWEEN 16 AND 30 THEN CallLength ELSE 0 END) AS FifteenToThirty
FROM CallTable
```

But after re-reading the question, putting case statements up to 86400 is probably out of the question...  Oh well :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked at last:

```
SET @a:=-15, @b:=0;
SELECT  t.start_time, t.end_time, count(c.duration)
FROM    calls c,
        (
        SELECT  (@a:=@a+15) as start_time, (@b:=@b+15) as end_time 
        FROM    `calls`  
        GROUP BY
                 cdr_id
        ) as t
WHERE   c.duration BETWEEN t.start_time and t.end_time
GROUP BY
        t.start_time, t.end_time
```

Comment: This will work if your table always contains more than 5760 rows.

Comment: Although this may work, you really should check the performance vs. Kouber's method. You're basically taking a procedural approach and applying it in a relational database which is built for set-based operations.